# Кнопки с кастомным Shape

Tags: android, shape, graphics

Как с помощью shape-ов в xml можно задачать фигуру "полукольцо" и фигуру "полукольцо с вырезом в центе"?

Смысл: нужно сделать две кнопки рядом в форме полукольца и поверх них еще полукольцо.
Пока что, не нашел как это сделать шейпами. На канве рисовать разве что:(

Картинко:
[image]

Comment: Убил бы дизайнера за такой "полет мысли"...

Comment: Я тоже, но останусь без работы:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой вариант еще проще.
Сделать обычные кнопки и правильно разложить все по слоях. У тебя на скрине 4 кнопки - их ложи на леяут, а все закругления - это будет просто рисунок с закруглениям и альфа-канал...

Comment: статичный рисунок положить поверх кнопок? ну да, мысль)

Comment: ну так и надо.. если ты не гуру верстки.. причем, что бы не заморачиватся с хмлками, я вешал листенер на эти кнопки и подменял бэкграунд при нажатии, отжатии, фокусе и тд.. может это и не правильно с идеологии разработки на андроиде - но экономит время в проектах.

Comment: тут даже не в верстке дело, а скорее в умении рисовать на канве и шейпах) хотя на счет последних неуверен, что они помогут сделать такое полудуговатое чудо!

Answer (score 2):

Делали как-то с @gorets похожую штуку:
[image: текст с тучками]

За основу брали [нечто такое](http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/view/BubbleTextView.java?r=15)

Хотя это все происходило с `TextView`, но думаю и с `Button` не должно возникнуть проблем.

В оконцове в декларации лэйаута использовали что-то типа:

```
<ru.ivanovpv.gorets.psm.controls.ReceivedBubbleTextView
    android:id="@+id/receivedMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:maxEms="10"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="36dip"
    android:paddingTop="24dip"
    android:paddingRight="36dip"
    android:paddingBottom="24dip"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:maxWidth="150dp"

    android:text="Received message"
/>
```

Comment: закругления - тру, но смысл же в полукольце белого цвета, внутри которого кнопки. Шейпами как такое сделать? Овал и сдвигать на минус вниз?! Хз

Comment: Сделай 2 кнопки в виде четвертинок круга - в чем проблемы то?

Comment: Без фотошопа?

Comment: Конечно, берешь канвас и на нем [рисуешь Arc](http://android-coding.blogspot.com/2012/04/draw-arc-on-canvas-canvasdrawarc.html)